# Is pl/sql don't use sql*plus command in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

example:

```
create or replace procedure DEMO is
begin
    --host dir
    --execute immediate 'host dir';
end DEMO;
```

I pupose invoke window's procedure in Oracle.

I try to use @command in sql*plus, but it discontent my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Stored procedures run on the database server.  `SQL*Plus` commands are executed on the client.  You cannot, therefore, use `SQL*Plus` commands in a stored procedure.

There is no way realistically for a stored procedure to get a directory listing for a directory on the client machine.  (You could, I suppose, have the client expose a shared directory and mount that from the server and the read the contents from the database but that isn't something that would be realistic in the vast, vast majority of cases).  A stored procedure can potentially call out to the database server's operating system using a Java or CLR stored procedure or, depending on the version, using the `dbms_scheduler` package.  But there are a lot of security issues to be concerned about before implementing something like this.